# STM32F4 Error Handler and allowed operations

Tags: stm32

Summary: In a hard fault, where can I put out the debug information?

- EEPROM via SPI?
- UART?
- USB?

Details:

I have the problem that the error handler gets triggered once a while, not reproducible. I suspect it is a hard fault as with the Error_Handler() I do print out something to the USB port but do not receive anything.

The standard way to expose the hard fault information is to printf to the debug port. But since that happens on a moving device and only once within hours, I can't have a debugger connected all time.
I assume that within a hard fault only so much can be done, e.g. USB does not work any longer, UART does not and writing to an EEPROM via SPI does not either. Is that correct? If yes, what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should of course assume that the system memory and peripherals are in an unpredictable state, and re-initialize everything that is going to be used in the handler.

- The stack may be corrupt, or the stack pointer invalid. Save all registers and relocate the stack to a known safe place in internal SRAM as the very first thing in the fault handler, without calling *any* functions. Better implemented in assembly.
- Pet the watchdog.
- Reset all internal peripherals using the RCC reset registers.
- Set internal clocks to a known safe frequency.
- Reset external peripherals and buses if applicable, e.g. if the external memory has a reset line, pulse it. If you are going to write to an I<sup>2</sup>C EEPROM, pulse SCL 10 times to reset the bus.
- `printf()` and the `stdio` infrastucture have way too much internal state, e.g. output buffers and work area allocated with `malloc()`, so it would be better not using them, but simple output functions for text and hex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The hardfault handler is executing code, you can do as you wish in there, but be aware that as you're there something has gone wrong. If you were using USB it could be your stack is in an erroneous state, as such, you may need to completely reinitialise it and the peripheral. You may have overflowed your stack, so that could be sanitized.

There is nothing stopping you running complicated code in the exception handler. The handler does however have a fixed priority of `-1`, so you won't be able to service any interrupts, as they won't interrupt the exception handler. That could well be the cause of your peripherals not working, try polling them instead.

A solution if you can't get them going is to have a block of memory defined in your linker script which is uninitialised on reset, store whatever pertinent information you have there, reset, and on reset in your main code check that memory area and output whatever you stored over whatever medium you wish. If it's not much data and you're not already using them, the RTC peripheral in the STM32 has some registers which are free to be used for arbitrary data, and aren't affected by reset.